# Receive error when writing table data to text file

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've tried the following hoping to write records from table to text file and have received following error:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced option',1
reconfigure

exec sp_configure  xp_cmdshell,1
reconfigure


DECLARE @OutputFile NVARCHAR(100) ,    @FilePath NVARCHAR(100) ,    @bcpCommand NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT Name FROM Customer " queryout '
SET @FilePath = 'C:\'
SET @OutputFile = 'testFile.txt'
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FilePath + @OutputFile + ' -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

Error:

```
SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Customer'.
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 8180
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
NULL
```

Comment: try prefixing the database and schema to your table `'bcp "SELECT Name FROM Database.dbo.Customer"`

Comment: @Lamak --- nvm, this worked. Thanks.